# Can pybullet load obj files using loadMJCF not loadURDF?

Tags: stl, rendering, .obj, bullet, pybullet

I would like to load robot descripted in XML fileformat.
But the thing is that it fails to load obj for visual effect. Is there way to process this rendering of .obj through xml file?

Checked loading .obj file using loadURDF works well but not in loadMJCF.